# capistrano-env file permissions

Tags: php, ruby, capistrano, web-deployment, capistrano3

I use gem `capistrano-env` and found a small problem. My deploy script is:

```
Capistrano::Env.use do |env|
  env.add 'DB_DSN', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname'
  env.add 'DB_USER', 'user'
  env.add 'DB_PASS', 'pass'
end
```

And this code create `.env` file on server after deploy. But! `.env` file permissions is 640 and my PHP script cannot read it. I can run `chmod` command after each deploy, but probably exist other nice solution?

**EDIT**

I created [pull request](https://github.com/masarakki/capistrano-env/pull/23) and add new `filemode` option into this gem. So, now solution is:

```
Capistrano::Env.use do |env|
  env.add 'DB_DSN', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname'
  env.add 'DB_USER', 'user'
  env.add 'DB_PASS', 'pass'
  env.filemode = 0644
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple options to make this nicer.

1. It doesn't look like capistrano-env supports a custom permissions setting, but perhaps that feature could be added! [Open an issue at GitHub](https://github.com/masarakki/capistrano-env/issues) and maybe the project maintainer will add it.
2. You could modify your `deploy.rb` to run the necessary `chmod` command for you. That way you wouldn't have to manually run chmod after each deploy.

Something like this:

```
# In deploy.rb
after "capenv:copy", "capenv:chmod" do
  on roles(:all) do
    execute "chmod", "a+r", "#{release_path}/#{Capistrano::Env.filename}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now I am currently using option # 2, but I thought about more nice solution. Ok I will try open new issue at GitHub.

Comment: I created pull request into this gem. See my updated answer.

Comment: Congrats on the getting the PR merged!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [capevn code](https://github.com/masarakki/capistrano-env/blob/master/lib/capistrano/env/v3/tasks/env.rake) the upload is done in a single task. You can locally override the definition of that task so you can change the file permissions.  Put something like the following in deploy.rb

```
namespace :capenv do
  desc 'copy .env to release_path'
  task :copy do
    on roles(:all) do
      upload! StringIO.new(Capistrano::Env.to_s), "#{release_path}/#{Capistrano::Env.filename}", mode: 'a+r'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Joshua for code sample. I created pull request on github and add new option into this gem. See my updated answer.

Comment: @stepozer Neat! Great job with the pull request.